# Save prediction to json or txt file and also save output video file in yolov3 object detection - Google colab

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory, yolo

Object detection on https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/ is working and the output is saved to an `.avi` file. I also want to save the predictions to a `json` or `txt` file.

This is the code I ran:

```
./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights -dont_show test_vid.mp4 -i 0 -out result.json -out_filename output.avi -ext_output -dont_show
```

But only the video output is saved. I want the predictions also to be saved to `json` or `txt` file. What am I doing wrong here? Is there any other way to do it?

I'm new to computer vision and need some help with this. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the function definition of [demo](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src/demo.c) here:

```
void demo(char *cfgfile, char *weightfile, float thresh, float hier_thresh, int cam_index, const char *filename, char **names, int classes, int avgframes,
    int frame_skip, char *prefix, char *out_filename, int mjpeg_port, int dontdraw_bbox, int json_port, int dont_show, int ext_output, int letter_box_in, int time_limit_sec, char *http_post_host,
    int benchmark, int benchmark_layers)
```

It does not have an argument called `-out`.

**If demo is what you want to use, with the existing code you have two options:**

1. Save results to video file: `-out_filename res.avi`
2. Get results online over the network by using your soft or Web-browser: `-json_port 8070 -mjpeg_port 8090`

With existing code `-out` is provided with `detector test` only. From [this](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src/detector.c) function definition:

```
void test_detector(char *datacfg, char *cfgfile, char *weightfile, char *filename, float thresh,
    float hier_thresh, int dont_show, int ext_output, int save_labels, char *outfile, int letter_box, int benchmark_layers)
```

To process a list of images `data/train.txt` and save results of detection to `result.json` file:

```
./darknet detector test cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov4.cfg yolov4.weights -ext_output -dont_show -out result.json < data/train.txt
```

**Note that, this is meant for doing detection on set of input images and save results to `json`.**

Check [here](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-use-on-the-command-line) for all possible commands along with flags and arguments, their usage is explained well.

**If you want to run detection on input video and save predictions as `json`, you have two options:**

1. Convert video to set of input images using opencv and use following command:

`./darknet detector test cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov4.cfg yolov4.weights -ext_output -dont_show -out result.json < data/train.txt`

2. Change the code to include `-out` functionality in demo:

You need to include this argument to demo function in [demo.h](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src/demo.h#L8), [yolo.c](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src/yolo.c#L366), [detector.c](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src/detector.c#L2022), [demo.c - 1](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src/demo.c#L133) and [demo.c - 2](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src/demo.c#L416):

```
 `char *outfile`
```

Add following code snippet to `demo.c`:

```
FILE* json_file = NULL;
if (outfile) {
    json_file = fopen(outfile, "wb");
    if(!json_file) {
      error("fopen failed");
    }
    char *tmp = "[\n";
    fwrite(tmp, sizeof(char), strlen(tmp), json_file);
}
```

Add this snippet [here](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src/demo.c#L280):

```
    if (json_file) {
        if (json_buf) {
            char *tmp = ", \n";
            fwrite(tmp, sizeof(char), strlen(tmp), json_file);
        }
        ++json_image_id;
        json_buf = detection_to_json(dets, nboxes, l.classes, names, json_image_id, input);

        fwrite(json_buf, sizeof(char), strlen(json_buf), json_file);
        free(json_buf);
    }
```

Close `json` file [here](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src/detector.c#L1740):

```
 if (json_file) {
        char *tmp = "\n]";
        fwrite(tmp, sizeof(char), strlen(tmp), json_file);
        fclose(json_file);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where I should add this code in **demo.c** ? Inside **demo function**? 

`if (outfile) {
    json_file = fopen(outfile, "wb");
    if(!json_file) {
      error("fopen failed");
    }
    char *tmp = "[\n";
    fwrite(tmp, sizeof(char), strlen(tmp), json_file);
}`

Comment: @SaranRaj You can add it [here](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src/demo.c#L167).

Comment: @VenkateshWadawadagi I did the same but I encountered many errors. Errors like: "too few arguments in function call", "identifier 'json_buf' is unidentified" and many more.

Comment: @Virtuall.Kingg Please cross check the darkness code version that you're using, and also you're passing arguments to the function appropriately. If you're still stuck with weird errors, post it as a separate question

Answer (score 0):

If you add to your command  `>result.txt` it will save all results in it. It worked for me. I was training yolov4 on colab and all display info of demo function were saved to the file result.txt